# How do I customize "Login Error invalid login credentials"?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I am having trouble with a login issue on Parse.com.

When the user enters wrong information for the username or password, a message shows up:

***Login Error*** invalid login credentials

Thats is functionally fine, but I can’t figure out where this message is coming from, in order to customize it.

I first thought the method

```
- (void)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController
    didFailToLogInWithError:(NSError *)error
```

would be what I was looking for. But after trying out, it appears that it is not.
Even if I overwrite it, the old message is still coming up, on top of my overwritten method.

Any idea about how I can change this message?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to customize by doing the following:

[From Parse.com](https://parse.com/questions/override-default-pfloginviewcontroller-login-error) - The alert cannot be removed in the current SDK, but you can provide a Localizable.strings file that overrides the following strings:

```
NSString *ok = NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK");
NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"Your Error Title", @"Login Error");
NSString *message = NSLocalizedString(@"Your Error Message", @"invalid login credentials");
```

Replace Your Error Title or Message with what you would like to display to the user.

Comment: Your solution works partially.
By adding this (as a test):

"OK" = "OOKK";
"Login Error" = "LLogin EError";
"invalid login credentials" = "iinvalid llogin ccredentials";
in the Localizable.strings file, the first and second strings get altered as expected, but the last one doesn’t change. Or let me know if you had something else in mind.

Comment: I am not following your comment.
The only format I know for the Localizable.strings file is this:

`"XYZ" = "One string or another";`

Comment: If I put (copy-paste)  what you write in the Localizable.strings file, I get this message:
`Copy .strings file Error: Read failed: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format` from Xcode.

Comment: My apologize. Was not thinking. I see that the last string is not changing on mine as well. Trying to figure out right now.

Comment: I am unable to get the last string to take. I even copied the text from logs to ensure spelling and it still doesn't take.

Comment: I suppose the ID of the string (to use in Localizable.strings to identify it) is not the same as the string itself, like it is the case for the first and second.
Or worse, it is hard coded in the code and doesn't allow any change.
But it should be easier (easy) to customize anyway (if Parse did a good job).

Comment: I will see what I can find over the next day or two. I did notice that in the parse framework, their localizable.strings file has OK and Login Error, but does not have the invalid login credentials.