# Uncustomizable message using PFLogInViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform, customization, pfloginviewcontroller

Looking at the documentation:
https://www.parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views,
https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFLogInViewController.html
and trying various things, as well as browsing the net;
I can’t find any way to customize this message to my taste:
`“Login Error invalid login credentials”`

I already made a post related to this issue:
[How do I customize "Login Error invalid login credentials"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314048/how-do-i-customize-login-error-invalid-login-credentials)
with not much success.

I don’t know if that qualifies as a bug, but in case there is no solution to this problem; there is clearly something missing in the API.
If anyone thinks I am missing something, please let me know.

Comment: You have to change the localized strings in order to customize. Just google that. I'm on my phone right now. Options will populate though. Look for the ones answered by parse developers (hector etc)

Comment: I already tried that. But part of it seems to be uncustomizable. See my previous post (and comments): `How do I customize "Login Error invalid login credentials"?`
Unless you know the way to get the last part working?

Comment: see our discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28486692/2353523). Especially the links and the github url in the comments.

Comment: I had a look but didn't find any thing for the "invalid login credentials" part.
May be I did not spend enough time, but it seems there is no easy solution (maybe no solution). I don't think I want to spend more time, only to adjust a message. That should be easy customization though: I wonder why `logInViewController:didFailToLogInWithError:` exists.

Comment: Did you see the comment with this link : https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#ui-string/iOS

Comment: Yes, but nothing for the part I am looking for.
Some strings are indeed customizable and I used this already.

Comment: I'll troubleshoot when I get to a computer. There's been a lot of updates to the framework since that post.